# May someone of you provide me (if possible) an expression for the F.T. of $\tan(x)$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, mathematica

So here it is my problem: I need the Fourier Transform of the tangent function, namely:

> $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \tan(x)\ e^{-ikx}\ dx$$

I tried for hours by hands and I got literally nothing.

I have W. Mathematica v. 11.01 on my computer, but after having run the command it took like forever (I let it run for $40$ minutes at least) then I aborted the operation (it was still running).

Probably my computer has not the necessary amount of power to compute it.

Could anyone of you try, please?

Unless there is some tricky trickilicious trick by which one can compute it by hands...

**P.s. The integral is divergent, I need either a principal value treatise or a sort of regularization".**

Comment: You are aware of that the integral is divergent? Do you intend to use some principal value or so?

Comment: @mickep Yes, sorry I forgot to write it!

Comment: Since $\tan x$ is periodic with period $\pi,$ it will be something like $\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} a_i\delta(k-\pi j),$

Comment: If it helps, Bracewell lists the inverse Fourier Transform of $\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{1}{2}\cot{\pi s}$ as $Shah(x)H(x)$.  Where $H(x)$ is the unit step, $Shah(x)$ is an infinite train of dirac $\delta(x)$ functions, and the Fourier transform with kernel $e^{-2\pi i xs}$ is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of generalized functions, the tangent function has representation

$$\begin{align}
\tan(x)\sim 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\sin(2nx)
\end{align}$$

Then, using the Fourier Transform

$$\mathscr{F}\{1\}=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty (1)e^{-ikx} \,dx=\sqrt{2\pi} \delta(k)$$

we find that

$$\mathscr{F}\{ \tan\}(k)=i\,\sqrt{2\pi } \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\left(\delta(k+2n)-\delta(k-2n)\right)$$

Comment: The first relation you wrote is neither an identity nor an approximation. Does it mean "asymptotic"? Or is that some different relation? (I did not knew that, by the way. Thank you!)

Comment: @VonNeumann Do you know what a generalized function is?

Comment: I think I more often heard about distributions, which are generalized functions. Unless there are "other types" of generalized functions...

Comment: You're correct.  A [Generalized Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_function) is a distribution.  I used the symbol $\sim$ rather than $=$ to highlight that the relationship is not an equality in the conventional sense (the series doesn't even converge in general).

Comment: Now it's all clear!